# TestNG behaves different in Eclipse and in ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant, testng

I am using the Eclipse-PlugIn for TestNG which works fine and executes my tests. But this is only when I start it out of Eclipse.

If I use Apache ANT with a specified testng-target it says that TestNG can't execute the tasks. The problem is that there is a argument type mismatch. That is indeed correct. I have a before method which gets a lot of parameters defined in the testng.xml file and one parameter from a data provider. And the one parameter from the data provider isn't declared as a parameter of the testng.xml file of course.

The funny thing is, the eclipse-plugin can handle it correct and works as I want but the testng-version of ANT can't handle it. So I am asking myself, are there different versions of testng? Maybe one can handle it, the other not?

EDIT: This is the stacktrace. It is exactly the same in the eclipse plugin and in ANT. But in the eclipse plugin there is no exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:525)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:202)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:613)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:34)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:351)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$CountDownLatchedRunnable.run(ThreadUtil.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Run with verbose=10, this should give you more information about what's going on. If it doesn't help, trim down your Eclipse project so I can build it and email it to me, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version is 6.3.1, I suppose that this is the one the eclipse plugin is using.
The one in ant was probably downloaded/installed by you.

If you open the one used in ant like a zip file you can take a look at the manifest in `META-INF/Manifest.mf`.
This will tell you the version of this jar.

This probably is a version mismatch between the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I want ant to use the jar generated with my new code. In order to do this, I had to open the properties of my project, search for TestNG and check "Use TestNG project jar"

[image]